# SQL Server 2017 Edition Upgrade from Standard to Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to upgrade from a **SQL Server 2017** *Standard* Edition to an *Enterprise* Edition and can't seem to find my **instance** to be available to upgrade it.

When I start up the wizard and go to *Maintenance* tab I click the "Edition Upgrade", but once I get past the Product Key, License Term and Global Rules, it does not prompt me to select an instance. It don't allow me to update the Database Engine or Server Agent.

I have been following the process to do this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup).

I have tried to restart the **Database Engine** and **Agent** services, but it doesn't seem to pick up the instance as suggested.  I have also stopped the windows services, but still no success.

I don't have any experience doing a SQL Server edition upgrade, so not sure if there is some additional step I might be missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about backing up your current databases, uninstall you current instance and then install enterprise edition and restore the backups into the new instances?

Comment: @Hackerman that is what I was thinking about doing, but was curious as to why it wasn't working as expected.